# Facebook SDK error in source code //connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, fbsdk

It seems that there is a mistake in the source code of Facebook SDK.
I went to this link and I found out that the syntax is incorrect at this line:

`if(document.='string'?m:k.ent())m();h=null;}functi ind',true",funn k=t{'use 'k){se;}e);`

For some reason, there is "." after document and "functi" means nothing.
This doesn't make sense. Any suggestion about how to fix this? 
As a work around I am using another FB's source code which is this:

`//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5`

Comment: Unable to reproduce. https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js looks good to me.

Comment: All looks good to me too. What URL did you see this error in?